# Finitely generated free modules are isomorphic to their dual

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Can u help me show that if $M$ is a finitely generated free module and $A$ a commutative ring then $M\cong\operatorname{Hom}_A(M,A)$?

Using the fact A has invariant dimension property and prove their bases have the same cardinality I tried to create generators for $Hom_A(M,A)$ that I name $e_{vi}(x)$ where its $1_A$ if $v_i=x$ and $0$ otherwise (where all the $v_i$ are the generators of M), but I'm not sure they generate the whole set of homomorphisms. Well any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ generate $M$. By linearity, any $\phi\in\textrm{Hom}_A(M,A)$ is defined by where it sends $\phi(e_i)$ for each $i$. This allows us to construct $$\begin{align} M & \longrightarrow \textrm{Hom}_A(M,A) \\ \sum\lambda_ie_i & \longmapsto \{\phi : e_i \mapsto \lambda_i\}\end{align} $$ with inverse $$\begin{align} \textrm{Hom}_A(M,A)& \longrightarrow M \\ \phi & \longmapsto \sum\phi(e_i)e_i\end{align} $$

Comment: Alright , i was able to prove that they were inverse to each other so they are isomorphic, just creating that first homomorphism doesnt seem to be very natural to me, do you have any intuition about it ?

Comment: Think about what you would do in dimension 1: i.e. proving $A$ and $\textrm{Hom}_A(A,A)$ are isomorphic. In this case, you notice that any map is defined by where you send $1_A$, and hopefully the first homomorphism would follow from that observation. Extrapolating this to dimension $n$ gives the homomorphism I've written above

Comment: Alternatively, the second map might be easier to come up with, and then coming up with the first map as the inverse of the second might be easier

Comment: Alright yeah that does seem to make sense, thanks!!

Comment: Just a quick question, isnt my initial reasoning correct that if i prove that they have the same number of generators then they are isomorphic since A is a commutative ring and has the invariant dimension property, because i think its rather straightforward to prove that those $e_{vi}$ are going to generated the whole set of homomorphisms when M is finitely generated.

Comment: Yes it is, and you can definitely do it by proving your indicator functions are linearly independent and spanning. However, I'd say that constructing those maps are more informative - any two free modules of the same (finite) dimension are isomorphic but usually not canonically. Those maps give us a canonical isomorphism between $M$ and $\textrm{Hom}_A(M,A)$, its *dual*, and similar maps can be constructed for other algebraic objects and their duals.

Comment: Alright thanks !!